# Locking on insert

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a pretty simple case I am a bit confused about. I want to insert a record, which must be unique. Thus, if it exists, I need to either replace it or delete and re-insert it. If it does not exist, I need to create it - but need to worry about someone else doing the check and creating the same one at the same time.

Can anyone recommend the "correct" way of doing this with respect to locking in MySQL? i.e. preventing someone from concurrenly doing the same thing?

If I do this - I am not protected against concurrent inserts of records with the same condition:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SELECT (condtions) FOR UPDATE
if rows exist 
  UPDATE
else
  INSERT
COMMIT
```

Seems like a simple thing - obviously very rusty at SQL...

**Also:**

If I am holding a lock, and another user tries to read/write something that is held by the lock - will the other user receive an error, or will their processing just get delayed until the lock is released?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `REPLACE` (if exist, remove, and re-insert)  - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replace.html

OR

```
insert ... on duplicate key update ... /* does not remove, just update */
```

Comment: Super! One more related question: The data in my database is a map - thus each "unique" record (if it exists) has an X and Y coordinate. Can I create a table that uses *two* fields which together need to be unique - or do I need to merge the numbers into a single value and make that the unique key?

Comment: sure, this is known as Natural Key - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_key as opposite of surrogate key - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key . Pros and cons can be found on SO and also discuss at the wiki

Answer (score 0):

Heres's the complete guide for the same.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html

If I'm correct lock table with read access, do the transaction and unlock table.